# My code output repeats

Tags: c++

I'm doing this code for triangle finding perameters for right triangles
but the output seems to come out right but repeated

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    float c;
    vector<double> retval;
    double intiger;
    double p;
    double l = 25;
    float array[3];

    for (int b=1; b < l; b++) {
        for (int a=1; a < l; a++) {
            intiger = sqrt((b*b)+(a*a));
            c = sqrt((b*b)+(a*a));
            if (c == intiger) {
                array[0]=a;
                array[1]=b;
                array[2]=c;
                //int elements = sizeof(array);
                //cout << elements << endl;
                sort(array, array +3);
                //retval.push_back(a);
                //retval.push_back(b);
                //retval.push_back(c);
                if (c == a ) {
                    continue;
                }
                p = a + b + c;
                if (p > l) {
                    break;
                }
                //cout << "p == " << p << endl;
            } else {
                continue;
            }

            //if (retval.size()== 62)
            //cout << c <<endl;
            //cout << " a = " << a << " b = " << b << " c = " << c << " "
            cout << array[0] << " " << array[1] << " " << array[2] << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output comes out to be repeated twice.

```
3 4 5

3 4 5

6 8 10

6 8 10
```

I want to make it repeat only once.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Move the "cout" down 1 line, after the }.

Comment: i moved the cout but the codes came out right but it still repeats

Comment: The test you're using is really weird. Further, there exist formulas that can be used to **generate** integer solutions. Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples

Answer (score 3):

The reason why this repeats has to do with the sorting within the algorithm.  The nested loop ensures that you will get every numeric pair in both orders.  Example if you have `a == 3` and `b == 4` in the inner loop then you will also have `a == 4` and `b == 3` in the inner loop.

The main test for output is the following

```
intiger = sqrt((b*b)+(a*a));
c = sqrt((b*b)+(a*a));
if(c == intiger)
{
```

If this test works for `a` and `b` then it will work when the numeric pairs are reversed (if it works for 3, 4 then it will work for 4, 3.

Later on you sort the resulting output

```
sort(array, array +3);
```

This causes the different ordered pairs to have the same order in the array.  This final value is output and it looks like the same values are displayed twice.

To fix this do one of the following

1. Don't sort the array
2. Change the loop so you don't get both pairs of values.

Answer (score 0):

As JaredPar says dont let the a,b to get the same pair of values. like (3,4) and (4,3). If then in sorted order both will give you the same result as (3,4,5).

For that change the for loop as....

```
 for (int b=1; b < l; b++)
        for (int a=1; a < b; a++)
```

And you can modify your code's continue and break statements to improve reability like follows....

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    float c;
    vector<double> retval;
    double integer;

    double l = 25;
    float array[3];

       for (int b=1; b < l; b++)
          for (int a=1; a < b; a++) {

            integer = sqrt((b*b)+(a*a));
            c = sqrt((b*b)+(a*a));

            if (c != integer) 
            continue;


            array[0]=a;
            array[1]=b;
            array[2]=c;
            sort(array, array +3);

            if(c != a && a+b+c > l)
            break;

            cout << array[0] << " " << array[1] << " " << array[2] << endl;

            }


        return 0;
    }
```